# Nativescript swipe gesture not working on Android with ScrollView

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using a swipe gesture to turn pages. It works great on ios. However, the Android version isn't working where there is a scrollview in play.

I am using Nativescript Pro UI to have a side-drawer. I want to put the gesture on the

Inside of the tkMainContent there is a scrollview.

Swipe doesn't even log a console.log event when I swipe inside the scrollview area. Is there a way to get it to work for Android?

Here is my typescript code:

```
let cbView = this.contentbody.nativeElement;
    cbView.on('swipe', (args: SwipeGestureEventData) =>{  
    console.log("Swipe Direction: " + args.direction);
    let topNextView = cbView.getViewById('topNext');
    let topBackView = cbView.getViewById('topBack');
    this.playerService.setIsBusyLoading(false);
    if(args.direction === 1) {
        topBackView.notify({eventName: 'tap', object: topBackView});
    }
    if(args.direction === 2) {
        topNextView.notify({eventName: 'tap', object: topNextView});
    }
    });
}
```

As I said I"m not getting Swipe Direction 2 when swiping on Android. If I swipe above where I have the scrollview start, such as in the heading of my document, then it picks up the swipe.

Comment: It's because Android has to intercept the touch events from ScrollView, add the swipe event to the ScrollView itself, you should be good then.